# Add ability to specify if job was contract or not on Careers profile job history

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs, employers

When going through candidates, it's a little worrying to see that a candidate's work history has many previous jobs that only lasted for less than 6 months when I'm unsure if those were contract jobs or not.

If they are contract jobs, then it's fine, but it becomes worrying if they only stayed at full-time job for less than 6 months.

Can you please add the ability to specify if job was contract or not on Careers profile job history?

Answer (score 2):

This is typically something we expect the candidate to write into the free text form.  I guess we could put in a flag of some sort, but we mostly reserve those for things that become search filters for the employers.  Filtering based off of contract work (except in the case of seeing if someone is currently only contracting) doesn't feel very useful.

Yeah, I think I talked myself out of adding anything special here.  They should mention it, or it should come up when you talk with them.  If you like them enough based on what you see and have this reservation, it's probably best to clear the air at some point in the interview process.

Comment: Feature request can't be "by design"... think you meant to mark it [meta-tag:status-declined]?